# Display photo taken with kinect at runtime in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, kinect

I am taking an image with Kinect in C# and want to display it on the next page of the application.

I can acquire the image successfully and can store it successfully on disk since I'm able to send this image as an email attachment.

The photo acquisition code is:

```
        public void CaptureScreen(double x, double y, double width, double height)
    {
        int ix, iy, iw, ih;
        ix = Convert.ToInt32(x);
        iy = Convert.ToInt32(y);
        iw = Convert.ToInt32(width);
        ih = Convert.ToInt32(height);

        //  set the kinect hand icon invisible 
        kinectButton.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        kinectButton2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed; 
        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(iw, ih,
               System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
        g.CopyFromScreen(ix, iy, ix, iy,
                 new System.Drawing.Size(iw, ih),
                 CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);


        image.Save("../../Images/image_display.png");
        desk_input();
    }
```

I use the `image_display.png` file to display the image on the screen.

I'm using the following code for displaying the image:

```
 private void desk_input() {



        BitmapImage bi2 = new BitmapImage();
        bi2.BeginInit();


        bi2.UriSource = new Uri("/Images/image_display.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        bi2.EndInit();
        photo_preview.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        photo_preview.Source = bi2;

        Canvas.SetLeft(photo_preview, 750);
        Canvas.SetTop(photo_preview, 400);


    }
```

However, during run time, the photo taken when the application was run last time keeps being displayed instead of the current photo. I'm guessing this is because the `image_display.png` file is added to the binary when the application is compiled.

So can you suggest a way where I can display the image taken with the kinect immediately?

**Edit:** I solved the problem by refreshing the bitmap cache as follows:

```
 private void desk_input() {



        BitmapImage bi2 = new BitmapImage();
        bi2.BeginInit();


        bi2.UriSource = new Uri("/Images/image_display.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        bi2.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad; //Changed - Reload the file
        bi2.EndInit();
        photo_preview.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        photo_preview.Source = bi2;

        Canvas.SetLeft(photo_preview, 750);
        Canvas.SetTop(photo_preview, 400);


    }
```